# global-error.tsx don't catch error in next.js

Tags: next.js13

**app\global-error.tsx**

'use client';

```
export default function GlobalError({
  error,
  reset,
}: {
  error: Error;
  reset: () => void;
}) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Something went wrong!</h2>
        <button onClick={() => reset()}>Try again</button>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

**a\page.tsx**

```
export default function Page_A() {
  throw new Error();
  return <div>Error</div>;
}
```

When I go to /a. global-error.tsx don't catch error. why ?

Comment: What happens then? Did you figure it out?